# Emacs ido-mode to insert common block at point

Tags: emacs, elisp

I just started using `ido-mode` for selecting buffers and files and I am very pleased with it so far. Now I got the idea: *It could be nice to use this to insert common blocks of text in the buffer too*.

Is this simple to achieve? For example, I imagine that this could be done using 
a text file of text blocks (or several files, one for each major mode for example) separated by say `"---"`. For example:

```
from numpy import *
---
def f():

  return
---
import os,sys
---
```

Then pressing, say <kbd>F1</kbd> would bring up the `ido-mode` completion buffer, and typing `fr` would be enough to select the first item `from numpy import *`, and pressing enter would insert it into the buffer at point.

(Also, to add new blocks to the file of completion blocks, one could imagine selecting the region in the buffer and then pressing, say <kbd>F2</kbd> to store it in the file for later use).

Comment: Check out yasnippet, which has the functionality you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which aspect in particular you needed help with: reusing ido or storing a list of completions.  However, once you have a list of completions (perhaps just a list defined in your .emacs?) , check out the function ido-completing-read.  I use it to use ido functionality on my kill ring like so:

(ido-completing-read "Yank text: " kill-ring)